# iOS: How to Save NSAttributedString to String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a NSAttributedstring from my UIText View ,
and I wanna translate it to NSString and save it.
so I use these code to made it:

```
- (NSString *)attriToStrWithAttri:(NSAttributedString *)attri{
NSDictionary *tempDic = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                          NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]};
NSData *htmlData = [attri dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attri.length)
                     documentAttributes:tempDic
                                  error:nil];

return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData
                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

}

When next time ,I want to display it in my textView,I use these code to translate it to NSAttributedString:

```
 NSAttributedString *attrStr =[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[self.richTextString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]}
                                                       documentAttributes:nil
                                                                    error:nil];
```

And I found that its Attributed changes.
For example:
I save it.
[image]

And then I load and translate to NSAttributedstring.
[image]

How can I deal with this problem.

Comment: @Codus Oh，I mean that I got some attributedstring form my textview，and save it as html+css string just like pic1.the next time I load this string and translate it to attributedstring and found some attribute value changed.Is there any problem in my code to translate NSString to NSAttributedstring ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because HTML4 VS HTML5.

1. You will got `HTML4` when you translate `NSAttributedString` to html.
2. But the content of html just translated seems should be `HTML5`. When you put the html back, it will look bigger.

So when you keep translate  `NSAttributedString` and put html back, it will keep generate HTML4 and put it back as HTML5(make font size bigger).

like this:

> NSAttributedString -> HTML4 -> NSAttributedString

[image: Keep export NSAttributedString to html and put it back]

You can try to erase HTML4 mark to let `NSAttributedString` correctly parse translated html to HTML5.

ex: change `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

like this:

> NSAttributedString -> HTML4 -> as HTML5 -> NSAttributedString

[image: Keep export NSAttributedString to html and put it back as HTML5]

Comment: Thanks a lot and I found that it's a problem about pt and px.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *str = [attri string];
```